# Biking to the airport / leaving a bike for a week

Tags: security

I'd like to try riding to the airport or to public transit when I travel. Does anybody do this? Any suggestions for how to secure a bike if you're going to need to leave it for a week or so?

Comment: Different airports will offer different options, some have bike lockers (lockers big enough to put your bicycle into), others bike valet parking. Check your local airport website. San Francisco has a nice page all about bicycle parking at http://www.flysfo.com/to-from/biking

Comment: Sure enough, [Seattle also has bicycle parking](http://www.portseattle.org/Sea-Tac/Parking-and-Transportation/Ground-Transportation/Pages/Bicycle-Resources.aspx). I figured I would have noticed it, but it is kind of well hidden. Can't tell from the web site how well secured it is, or if there is a fee.

Comment: I'd probably be inclined to take public transit to the airport and leave the bike in my apartment. Might cost a few more bucks, but still, saves me money in the long haul.

Comment: The catch for me is that the nearest public transit is about 6 km from my house, so I need to leave the bike someplace… So, I've been trying to think of places that would be reasonably safe.

Comment: @GlennGervais - SFO's bike parking leaves a lot to be desired since they only have open racks no lockers. They have surveillance cameras, but I know from experience that cameras don't protect a bike. Also bike parking is limited to 14 days so if you're going for a long trip, don't bring your bike or they'll confiscate and dispose of it.

Comment: @dlu, I agree with leaving the bike at home and taking the transit.  However, can you get a taxi to cover some of the route.  Does your city have a public bike share?  Rent a tandem bike and buy your friend a 6 pack of beer to help out.

Comment: @BPugh No need rent a tandem, we have one :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't uncommon in our neck of the woods. If you're a light packer, taking your bike the the airport can be a huge money saver.

If your airport doesn't have a bike locker, bring two trusty u-locks with you. Use one u-lock to secure your front wheel and down-tube to one pole, and the other u-lock secure your rear wheel to another pole (please, never use a cable lock unless you're hoping to file an insurance claim for your bike when you get back into town). Try not to use your favorite bike if you have more than one.

Either leave fancy accessories and lights at home or take them off and take them with you when you arrive at the airport.

If your seat post uses a quick release, I would recommend replacing it with a bolt-on clamp. This won't guarantee your seat (or other bolted on parts) is safe from a well prepared perpetrator, but the majority thieves are looking for a quick and easy score, and will skip over your well-secured components in favor of lower hanging fruit.

(photo borrowed from lifehacker)

[image: locks]

Comment: I would go one step further and have a dedicated beater.  I have a single speed that is actually a decent bike but intentionally looks like trash.  Not likely to steal it, not much to strip, and if it is stolen I can live with it.  Great answer.  +1

Comment: I normally use 1 U-lock and 1 cable lock plus pinhead skewers etc. I'd add the second U-lock for long term use like you say. The easiest way to steal the bike is then to cut the rack.

Comment: You should use *two **different types** of lock*. Any lock can be broken; if you use two of the same type then a thief who turns up with the required equipment to break it (in the case of a U-lock - a small jack) can break both.

Comment: @paparazzo my version is `never lock a bike you would cry for if stolen`.

Answer (score 7):

I left my bike at the airport for a week and would do it again. It seemed to be the safest place in the whole city, safer than my home.

It depends on where the bike racks are; here in Edinburgh they are right next to the entrance to the departure check-in hall. It's inside the vehicle perimeter, and a security guard stood with a submachine gun next to it. There are probably also numerous security cameras watching the whole entrance area (and unlike most urban cctv, they are properly monitored!).

If you only use a cheap lock that can be picked or cut with small tools, then your bike is at risk wherever you leave it. But any decent D-lock requires a power tool.

Now imagine the thief who drives his pickup truck through the security crash barriers and then takes out his noisy angle grinder right next to a submachinegun-armed security guard at the airport. I think he would be done for more than attempted bike theft :-)

An airport, even without any special bike security arrangement, has all the features of a very secure place. Lots of people at all time, regular security guard patrols, cameras, access control, etc.

So I really wouldn't worry too much, as long as you have a solid D-lock that needs bigger tools.

But leave your bike only at a designated bicycle parking area, don't lock it to any other railing or lamp-post like you would do in any other place. Then it might be you who will be in trouble with airport security....

Answer (score 0):

I have previously left my bike in Paris Beauvais airport (BVA) which is not equipped for bicycle parking at all.

I only found out that there is no dedicated bicycle parking when I arrived. The airport is ~90km from where I live and I had 2 hours until take off, so cycling back home was not an option.

I locked the bike to the fence on the inner side of the car park. Only had one D-lock with me, so did the best I could with it.

I was only away for a weekend. Bike was in place and intact when I came to pick it up:

[image]

Planning to cycle to BVA next weekend again. I will most likely use 2 or more locks.

Comment: Beware of doing this though - airports can be very twitchy about things left in unofficial places